# Why is my deferred.done() waiting for an AJAX call not resolved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have this piece of code:

```
Event = new Event();

// Create a deferred object
var dfd = $.Deferred();

// Add handlers to be called when dfd is resolved
dfd.done( Event.getEvents( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude ) ).then( function( data ){
    //rest of the code ..
    console.log("No!");
});
```

That doesn't behave the way I want. the done is never resolved and the `then()` is never triggered. Here is `Event.getEvents` (its in another file):

```
function Event() {

    this.getEvents = function( lat, lng )
    {
        var d = new $.Deferred();

        console.log("events");
        var key = getCookie("key");

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: server_url + 'event/eventssurrounding',
            headers: { 'X-API-KEY': key },
            data: { lat:lat, lng: lng, radius: radius, limit: limit, offset: offset },
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(results) {
                console.log('success');
                d.resolve = results.map( function ( event ) {

                    console.log(event);
                    var dist = JSON.stringify(event.distance);

                    console.log(dist);

                    return {
                        id: event.id,
                        name: event.name,
                        type: event.type,
                        desc: event.desc,
                        short_desc: event.desc.substring(0,200),
                        pic:  event_pic_url + event.picture,

                        place: {
                            id: event.placeId,
                            name: event.placeName,
                            type: event.placeType
                        },

                        dist: dist.substring(0,3),
                        lat: event.latitude,
                        long: event.longitude,
                    }
                });
                console.log("done");
                return d.promise();
            },
            error : function( xhr, type )
            {
                return null;
            } 
        });

        console.log("This shouldn't be logged before success.");

    }
};
```

I'd like the the `console.log("No!")` (in first piece of blog) to be triggered AFTER the AJAX call. But from what I see in my console log, the ajax call is executed after the "This shouldn't be logged before success." is logged. And the done is never triggered. I can't find out why.

here is my log:

```
events
This shouldn't be logged before success.
success
Object 
2.3322972250333
done
```

If I try with `$.when(Event.getEvents()` ... then the done is triggered immediately after "This shouldn't be logged before success."

How can I have my deferred object to be triggered after the AJAX call is over, when I return a promise ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Thanks but return $.AJAX is what I'm trying to avoid since there is some logic in the success method. And I want to return the filtered results only. Is doing return $.AJAX the ONLY way to use when/deferred ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite strange: you are tryig to pass a result of `getEvents` function to `$.when` (which should accept jQuery deferred objects), but `getEvents` has no return statement at all.

`$.when` gets `undefined` and has nothing to do actually. I guess your `getEvents` function might return a result from ajax call like this:

```
this.getEvents = function( lat, lng )
{
    // ... code
    return $.ajax({
       // ....
    });
}
```

I think this might be just a part of solution, but I believe it is a good start.

Next thing, why do you think this:

```
console.log("This shouldn't be logged before success.");
```

souldn't be executed before success? You started an **async** call and next statement is `console.log`. JS is single threaded and there is no chance that ajax call will finish work before this `log` call. This has no sence.

Next, what is the following code?

```
d.resolve =  ....
```

Isn't it should like

```
d.resolve ( // ... );
```

?